# How to create a label and input dynamically using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks, frontend, jsx

I'm working on creating a dynamic input form, where I want to click on a button and get a pop-up asking for label name and input type(Eg: number or text). Here is a mock-up of what I want to create. I should be able to even remove these newly created label and input.
[image: Pop Up appears asking for what I need the label name to be and the input type]

Once this is entered, it should create a new label and input form as below:[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm doing someone else's work but...)))

A quick example so you know which way to go:

**YourMainComponent.tsx:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DynamicForm } from "./dynamic-form";

export const Fields = () => {
  const [getFields, setFields] = useState([]);

  const addField = (field) => {
    setFields((prevState) => [...prevState, field]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DynamicForm onSubmit={addField} />
      {getFields &&
        getFields.map((field, index) => (
          <fieldset key={index}>
            <label>{field.label}</label>
            <input type={field.type} />
          </fieldset>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

**YourDynamicFieldCreateComponent:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const DynamicForm = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const [getField, setField] = useState({});
  const formSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Object.keys(getField).length > 0) {
      onSubmit(getField);
      setField({});
    }
  };
  const onFieldChanged = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "label-field") {
      setField((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        label: e.target.value
      }));
    } else if (e.target.id === "type-field") {
      setField((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        type: e.target.value
      }));
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>
      <fieldset>
        <label htmlFor="label-field">Your label </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="label-field"
          name="label-field"
          onChange={onFieldChanged}
        />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <label htmlFor="type-field">Your type of field </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="type-field"
          name="type-field"
          onChange={onFieldChanged}
        />
      </fieldset>
      <button>Add more</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Need add conditions and modals and other...

**This is not production code, use this only for learning**